# How do I select values of an object two levels deep using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

Form

```
public class Form
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Section> sections { get; set; }
    }
```

Section

```
public class Section
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool validated { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Question> questions { get; set; }
    }
```

Question

```
public class Question
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int required { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to search through the questions found in each section held within the form, check whether or not `Required` is set to 1 or 0, and pull back each question that is required.

I'm really not sure how to do this. At the moment I have this:

```
List<Question> requiredQuestions = 
                root.form.sections
                    .Where(x => x.questions.Where(y => y.required == 1))
```

But this code above is giving syntax errors. I'm still finding Linq somewhat confusing, can someone help with this please.

Comment: You can try to get questions for each section as a `List<List<Question>>` as this: `root.form.sections.Select(s => s.questions.Where(q => q.required == 1).ToList()).ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to get all the questions, and then filter on the `required` property:

```
List<Question> requiredQuestions = root.form.sections
    .SelectMany(section => section.questions)
    .Where(question => question.required == 1)
    .ToList();
```